# how do to trigger a driver without doing it in local space?

Tags: drivers

I want to lift two variables: eyeslashes and the eyelid, both with shapekeys and drivers attached. The eyeslash lift ups the eyelid with *child of* constraint BUT, i realized that when I lift the entire character the driver triggers, and start to lift.

How do I make this not happen?

[image: gz]

Closed eyes
[image: Closed eyes]

open eyes
[image: open eyes]

[image]